# ReactJs problem about Path Import Start from "./Start"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, path

Project\frontend>npm run dev

> frontend@0.0.0 dev
> vite

VITE v4.3.9  ready in 704 ms

➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
➜  Network: use --host to expose
➜  press h to show help
Failed to resolve import "./Start" from "src\App.jsx". Does the file exist?
12:01:31 [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "./Start" from "src\App.jsx". Does the file exist?
Plugin: vite:import-analysis
File: D:/TerProject/frontend/src/App.jsx:10:18

Comment: We really need to see your code to understand your imports and the cause of the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] to include better and more complete details regarding the issues) and what you've tried in correcting it/them. This might include also sharing a [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.